# IPv6 secure address delegation /64 subnet

Tags: networking, security, ipv6

I have taken upon myself the creation of an entire network, of which a part is a connection between my two (redundant routers) and their gateway (out of my scope).

Behind my routers are a couple of LANs, which also have IPv6 addresses.
Each of the 2 routers have a WAN connection, which is their uplink and connects to the third router, which is out of my scope. This WAN network is set up to be redundant using CARP, so this network has 4 addresses:

`1 for the CARP
2 for physical addresses of the 2 routers
1 for the uplink`

I have delegated a /64 prefix IPv6 network for this purpose (lets say 2001:db8:0:0::/64).

I have recently attended a bunch of IPv6 security courses and also read a lot myself and found 2 main things to concider here.

1. Direct connections should generally use /127 networks (RFC6164)
2. Addresses should be as random as possible, to complicate the
   scanning of the network. (RFC7721)

Now I want to assign addresses to the 4 interfaces from the /64 network. 
So there are two paths I see here. One is to create a /126 subnet, which only has 4 usable addresses and assign them to the 4 interfaces (2001:db8:0:0:11:22:33:4; 2001:db8:0:0:11:22:33:5; 2001:db8:0:0:11:22:33:6; 2001:db8:0:0:11:22:33:7). The other would be assigning the 4 interfaces random addresses from the whole /64 subnet (2001:db8:0:0:e2f:a9:7:3d6e; 3 other random addresses).

The first approach helps alleviate spoofing problems and the second - scanning problems.

Which would be the more advised way of assigning addresses in such a configuration? It is noteworthy that the addresses are global unicast addresses

Comment: A randomly generated address is not *required*, you can use easy to remember static addressing if you want.   Also,  please use either a real global address, or a documentation subnet. The 1:2:3:4 you have right now looks like a bogon.  https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts

Comment: Yes, it is not required. Then again it is best/recommended practice to do so. That is why I mentioned the 2 points I had learned from the security trainings and recommendations. But for those recommendations it was not specified what sort of network/connection it is meant for. So I`m asking for the best effort security measure on the global network/uplink connection.

Comment: It is likely that your `/64` network is simply a transit network, and your ISP is actually delegating a smaller prefix, e.g. `/48`. Some residential ISPs will only give a `/64` network to a customer, but your business should be getting a smaller prefix. Also, your firewall should prevent scanning from outside your network.

Comment: Sorry, that I was unclear. The infrastructure I'm creating is for a company and the LANs behind the 2 redundant routers are also having IPv6 GUAs (and ULAs as well). The uplink is yet another router of the company but managed by another administrator and serves an edge router role. The network for which I'm trying to figure out the addresses is just a branch and there are other networks like mine on a different connection of MY uplink (the edge router). Also, yes! I know there are other protections and FWs, but I`m trying to create a best effort defense and every step counts.

Comment: How about a random address, and the three next consecutive addresses?

Comment: That would be the scenario 1. Where I choose a random /126 from the /64 and assign the 4 addresses from that subnet.